# Should I contact HR before job start date?

Tags: job-offer

I signed a job contract with an August 1st, 2014 start date back in April, 2014. 
I haven't received anything from HR regarding background check, drug testing, orientation, etc. Though I've already signed the contract, I'm still a little worried. Anyone in the same boat or have experiences/advice with this? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An email asking politely about an update doesn't hurt.

Things that might be good to add to that email would be :

- How are my tests?
- Do you need anything else from me? (additional tests, or copy of some certificates or anything)

Make sure your tone in the email shows that you're contacting them to let them know that you're willing to help in case there are missing documents or anything as well as letting them know that you're interested in being updated of the tests you've been through.

Another good thing to do is to reread your contract for anything that might be of use.

Although generally since you already have a contract, things would go smooth and there's nothing to worry about regarding if you will really work or not.

Answer (score 3):

You need to follow up, pronto(*). It's a matter of due diligence, and it's a sanity check that you are indeed starting on 1 Aug 2014. If the reason they didn't contact further is that they're waiting for some document on info on you that you are not aware that they wanted you to give them, the joke is on you. Unfortunately, it's the kind of joke that will make you want to cry.

Again, make sure that you are starting on 1 Aug 2014 and line up whatever of your ducks need to be lined up.

(*) @RossAiken comments that if you send an email, you have to be cognizant their reply could end up in your Spambox instead of your Inbox. So, if you haven't received a reply from them in your Inbox, check the Spambox and follow up as well with a phone call.

Comment: Yeah, all OP needs to do is send an email saying "Hey, since there's slightly less than a month before I start, do you need any more information from me before day one?".  It's always possible that they did send an email that somehow ended up in a spam filter or something.

Comment: @RossAiken I incorporated your comment in my answer, with full attribution to you, of course.

Comment: Ah.  My comment was more about the fact that they could have sent something after hire with more directions that ended up getting auto-spammed (and possibly deleted).  Either way: Check your spam folder!!

Answer (score 2):

Contact the HR. I started my current job several months ago. Before the start day I sent an email to the HR (the HR person who was present during the interview and who posted me the contract) and asked who I should be looking for when I go there (one can't enter the building without an electronic pass), shall I be there at 8:30 (the beginning of the working day), do I have to bring any documents with me.

It turned out to be not just a sanity check but useful questions as she advised me to ask about her at the reception, so she can introduce me to the directors, to come later because everybody were going to be busy early in the morning, and to bring an ID so she can make a copy.